# Chart.js Dynamically Updating Chart with X Axis Time

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using Chart.js version 2.7.1 and I am dynamically updating my Line chart when temperature data comes in.

The problem is that the lines never pass the halfway mark of the x axis in time. Every time I update, the chart auto scales the right side ( max time ) of the x axis to be further out, so my data never approaches the right side of the chart. What I want is for the line to approach the right side, and only a small margin of time is extended into the future for the x-axis each time I update. How can I accomplish this?

Here is how I configure the chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('tempChart').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 320;
ctx.canvas.height = 240;

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
      labels: [],
      legend: {
         display: true
      },
      datasets: [{
          fill: false,
          data: [],
          label: 'Hot Temperature',
          backgroundColor: "#FF2D00",
          borderColor: "#FF2D00",
          type: 'line',
          pointRadius: 1,
          lineTension: 2,
          borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
          fill: false,
          data: [],
          label: 'Cold Temperature',
          backgroundColor: "#0027FF",
          borderColor: "#0027FF",
          type: 'line',
          pointRadius: 1,
          lineTension: 2,
          borderWidth: 2
      }]
  },
  options: {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Time ( UTC )'
          },
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            tooltipFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'MMM D, hh:mm:ss'
            }
          },
          ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90
          }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Temperature ( Celcius )'
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the chart:
[image]

Comment: Please provide the array that you are using for the data and the labels

Comment: without the data, it's hard to identify. share your data.

Comment: Can you try to replicate this behavior on JSFiddle or some other source? I created a JSFiddle but can't replicate what you are seeing. My lines stretch completely across the chart with the configuration you have above and some random data. Maybe you could update my example to show the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/k1g7zw2r/1/

Comment: Off topic but how is it possible to have 262 posts, ~402K post views and 8 gold badges but only 67 RP..? Of your 56 answers ***only 2 aren't accepted***, not to mention that you have 51 silver and 117 (no, that's not a typo) bronze badges. I'm baffled. At this rate you should have *at least* 3-5K RP.

Comment: @LogicalBranch he has more bronze badges than reputation. anyway, visit his activity tab, his reputation never went above 357, may be he offers bounty too frequently, or perhaps he is a bot :D

Comment: @Towkir Bots can give answers..? Man... A.I. really is taking over.

Comment: @LogicalBranch just kidding, I know you're too. BTW, visit his badges tab on activity tab, you'll see how he got the badges, like popular question, notable question and famous question. anyway, let's just keep the comment section clear.

Comment: @LogicalBranch he offered around [2600 points as bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688563/philbot?tab=bounties&sort=offered) that explains everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see in the following snippet and thanks also to [Daniel W Strimpel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7407935/daniel-w-strimpel) for creating the initial snippet, you problem is in the **hot** and **cold temperature** `data`.

```
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 19, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 20, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 21, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 22, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 23, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 24, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 25, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 26, 0) },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 27, 0) },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 28, 0) },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 29, 0) },
{ x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 30, 0) }
```

both of those arrays have `n` number of entries in the end missing the `y` coordinate including the **temperature value**. I recreated your scenario by deleting the `y` for the 5 last entries of the cold and hot temperatures `data`.

The `chart` will add the date to the `x axis`, but it will not add a `temperature` value and the line will not show up.

```
{x: new Data(2019, 0, 14, 1, 26, 0) }
```

The code snippet recreates your scenario, you can run it to understand the problem and fix it by adding the `y` value to the last 5 entries in the `getHotTempData` and `getColdTempData`

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('tempChart').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 320;
ctx.canvas.height = 240;

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
      labels: [],
      legend: {
         display: true
      },
      datasets: [{
          fill: false,
          data: getHotTempData(),
          label: 'Hot Temperature',
          backgroundColor: "#FF2D00",
          borderColor: "#FF2D00",
          type: 'line',
          pointRadius: 1,
          lineTension: 2,
          borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
          fill: false,
          data: getColdTempData(),
          label: 'Cold Temperature',
          backgroundColor: "#0027FF",
          borderColor: "#0027FF",
          type: 'line',
          pointRadius: 1,
          lineTension: 2,
          borderWidth: 2
      }]
  },
  options: {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Time ( UTC )'
          },
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            tooltipFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'MMM D, hh:mm:ss'
            }
          },
          ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90
          }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Temperature ( Celcius )'
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});

function getHotTempData() {
  return [
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 19, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 20, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 21, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 22, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 23, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 24, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 25, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 35 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 26, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 27, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 28, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 29, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 30, 0) }
  ];
}

function getColdTempData() {
  return [
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 19, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 23.5 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 20, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 23.5 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 21, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 23.5 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 22, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 23.5 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 23, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 23.5 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 24, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 23.5 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 25, 0), y: Math.random() * 0.5 + 23.5 },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 26, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 27, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 28, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 29, 0) },
    { x: new Date(2019, 0, 1, 14, 1, 30, 0) }
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="tempChart"></canvas>
```